# How to pass a variable in the variable var $paginate with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, date, pagination

My pagination worked perfectly like this :

```
var $paginate = array(
            'Article' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Article.visible' => true),
                'order' => array('Article.creation_date DESC', 'Article.id DESC'),
                'limit' => 11
            )
        );
```

But I want to filter my articles with a publication date like this

```
var $paginate = array(
            'Article' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Article.visible' => true,
                    'Article.publication_date <= ' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                'order' => array('Article.creation_date DESC', 'Article.id DESC'),
                'limit' => 11
            )
        );
```

But the date() function does not seem to be accepted.
It's not the good syntax.
Does anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't *think* this can be done; but you can paginate in an action directly `$this->paginate = array(...)` and could then use `date()` and other variables. I am not 100% sure *why* not however

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you will have to use `$this->paginate = array()` either in the action that you are paginating in, or in the `__construct()` function.

You cannot execute functions like that when the object is instantiated.

This is true for any type of method call at runtime.

Comment: Note: You do not have to use the `__construct()` function, you can also use `beforeFilter()`. I just said `__construct()` because he was trying to declare the variables at instantiation. Using __construct is the closest way around it.

Comment: Read this for more information about class properties: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a function in the declaration of an array at the class level. What you could do is to use a `beforeFilter()` callback in your controller to initialize the `$paginate` variable like this:

```php
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent :: beforeFilter();

    $this->paginate = array(
            'Article' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Article.visible' => true,
                    'Article.publication_date <=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                'order' => array('Article.creation_date DESC', 'Article.id DESC'),
                'limit' => 11
            )
        );
}
```